# Unable to generate multiple Images

Tags: javascript, dom

This is a game where 5 more images is to be added every time when a user click on last node of left side div.

If he clicks on some other node alert 'game over' should be displayed.

Issues:

1. TypeError: leftside.lastChild is null
2. How would I delete all nodes of both the right and left hand side div before calling the generateface function to generate new set of faces.

   ## Matching Game

   click on the extra smiling face on the left

   ```
   .smile {position:absolute}
   div {position:absolute; width:500px;height: 500px}
   #rightside {left:500px;border-left: 1px solid black}
   ```

   var numberOfFaces = 5;

   var leftside = document.getElementById("leftside");
   var rightside = document.getElementById("rightside");

   function generatefaces() {

   for (i=0;i`event.stopPropagation();
   numberOfFaces += 5;
   generateFaces();`


   };

   theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {

   theBody.onclick = null;
   alert("Game Over!");

   };

Comment: Do you receive any errors in your console?

Comment: There could be only one DOM with multiple elements!

Comment: @DavidR can you help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `px` to the `top` and `left` `style` property.
Change the code as below

```
ismile.style.top = topran + 'px'; 
ismile.style.left = leftran + 'px';
```

```js
var numberOfFaces = 5;

var leftside = document.getElementById("leftside");

function generatefaces() {

 for (i=0;i<=numberOfFaces;i++) {

ismile = document.createElement("img");

ismile.src = "http://orig00.deviantart.net/449c/f/2009/061/5/7/smiley_icon_by_emopunk23.jpg";

ismile.className = "smile";

var topran = Math.random() * 400;

topran = Math.floor(topran);

var leftran = Math.random() *400;

leftran = Math.floor(leftran);

ismile.style.top = topran + 'px'; 

ismile.style.left = leftran + 'px';

leftside.appendChild(ismile);

}

}
```

```css
.smile {position:absolute}
    div {position:absolute; width:500px;height: 500px}
    #rightside {left:500px;border-left: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<body onload="generatefaces()">
  <h1> Matching Game </h1>
  <p> click on the extra smiling face on the left </p>
  <div id="leftside"></div>
  <div id="rightside"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.
But, what is the logic of adding 'px' ?
when I have fixed a range.